# Laravel 4 how to use the route name alias (uses) with Route::controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Rather than using `Route::get`, `Route::post` etc for my controller requests I decided to use the `Route::controller` method, really helps cut down on code lines in `route.php`.

However I had previously set up some "route" names, for example my previous code included:

```
Route::get('admin/baserate/view', array('as' => 'baserateview','uses'=>'BaserateController@getView'));
```

but now I'm using `Route::controller` I don't know how to implement the route alias name "baserateview". My new code looks like:

```
Route::controller('admin/baserate', 'BaserateController');
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: but having an alias to a route to a controller wouldn't make any sense.. which method is being invoked then if you call a route via it's alias?

Comment: I was hoping to specify that one of the methods inside the controller has a named route without having to use two lines, for example if there was an array within the Route::controller line I could utilise.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this in the following way:

```
// User Controller
Route::controller(
    'users',
    'AdminUserController',
    array(
        'getView'     => 'admin.users.view',
        'getEdit'     => 'admin.users.edit',
        'getList'     => 'admin.users.list',
        'getAdd'      => 'admin.users.add',
        'getUndelete' => 'admin.users.undelete',
        'postDelete'  => 'admin.users.delete'
    )
);
```

Comment: Note, this does not work if you go to default action, e.g. index with /users (works only with /users/index)

Comment: I'm trying to do it but I'm getting the following error: Route [authpostlogin] not defined. In my routes.php I did: Route::controller('/', 'AuthController', [
        'getLogin'     => 'auth.getlogin',
        'postLogin'     => 'authpostlogin',
]);

Answer (score -1):

Ok so it isn't possible to do it all on the Route:controller line. I'd have to go with both lines:

```
Route::controller('admin/baserate', 'BaserateController');
Route::get('admin/baserate/view', array('as' => 'baserateview','uses'=>'BaserateController@getView'));
```

...which works fine. I was just hoping that there would be a way to specify that one of the methods inside the controller has a named route without having to use two lines

Thanks anyway

Comment: You should switch the order of these two lines so that the `Route::get()` takes precedence. If not, when you make a `GET` request to `admin/baserate/view` it will try to find it in the `BaserateController`. It may be working fine when you explicitly use the route alias, but not for regular requests.